# Please suggest a platform to port C# app to Mac?

Tags: java, .net, qt, macos, mono

Greetings,

I need to port this Windows utility: http://solinker.com to Mac.
The app was written in C#, .NET 2.0.

The main requirement is:
The app should be able to talk with AppleScript to interact with Photoshop. The program is small and UI is simple so I could consider to fully rewritte the app.

**Possible candidates are:**

- MonoMac
- Unity 3D (seems it doesn't required to install the Mono)
- XULRunner (Flickr Uploader written by XULR)
- QT
- Java (convert all the app to Java + 2 different connector to photoshop:
  for Mac and for Win)

I would be appreciate for any advice!

Comment: @Hovercraft - care to share your reasoning?

Comment: @Murat - the question is too open ended for StackOverflow. Can you focus it please - what aspect/s are you specifically interested in knowing about?

Comment: @Oded: He wants a mac-specific app, best to use a tool that is geared towards the creation of this. I've never used MonoMac, and I suppose he could try that, but do know that it's not a simple port of current C# .NET 2.0 to MonoMac, that it will involve quite a bit of effort. Why not re-write with platform-specific (or Java) tools.  But since my reply is all opinion rather than fact, I didn't place it in an answer but rather in a comment. I'm open to better solutions. :)

Comment: The platform should be able to interact with Photoshop via  AppleScript. Current windows version does it by COM & JavaScript. Probably this is the main requirement, plus the app should looks native on a Mac or at least with AIR Apps like style.

Comment: I've also found: http://www.monobjc.net. Thei home page says that  no Mono installation is needed prior the deployment of a Monobjc based application. Does anyone has exp. with monobjc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you check the documentation for MonoMac, you will see they have a packager which bundles all dependencies with the final app. So, no need for a seperate Mono install:

http://www.mono-project.com/MonoMacPackager

As for AppleScript, MonoDevelop does some wrapping of AppleScript. You should take a look at their source:

https://github.com/mono/monodevelop/blob/master/main/src/addins/MacPlatform/MacInterop/AppleScript.cs

I would say MonoMac is your best approach.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not experienced with others but can definitely suggest MonoMac. It looks and feels like any other Mac app while running on Mac. On the other hand, if the application was written with Visual Studio on Windows, it never properly works on MonoMac. So prefer MonoDevelop, if you go this route.

Comment: Can I launch AppleScripts via MonoMac? And do I need to install the Mono Framework (i guess yes) on a Mac?

Comment: @Nietz: thanks for the info about [MonoDevelop](http://monodevelop.com/). I'd not seen this before.  1+

Comment: @Murat, yes you'll need to install Mono Framework which is not much bigger than .NET Framework. I don't know if AppleScripts via MonoMac but trying googling, mono have excellent help forums where a lot of questions are already answered.

Comment: @NietzscheNorm: hmm... this means that the small utility installer size should be up to 10-20 mb larger.

Comment: Well yes, that is an unfortunate side affect, so that's up to you to decide.